# Android SQlite external import/create

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database of questions from an external SQlite manager. I would like to create a database on the first run of my app.

Is this possible instead of writing hundereds of lines of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can put the SQLite file in the [assets](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) folder of your Android project (or download it on demand) and copy it to the database folder of the installed app.

A tutorial explaining all the neccesary steps can be found [here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).

Note however that if you include the database file into your APK, it will consume twice the disk space than absolutely necessary (since it will exist twice, as asset and as usable database). Depending on the size of your database, it might be preferable to download it instead of embedding it into the APK.

Note furthermore, that prior to Android 2.3, any compressed asset file with an uncompressed size of over 1 MB cannot be read from the APK (and any asset will be compressed by default).

Comment: what do you mean by download it? Also can't the file just be deleted from the assets folder once used?

Comment: @Max AFAIK there is no way to remove assets at runtime. By downloading I mean downloading the file from the internet (e.g. using HTTP), which would reduce the size of your app installation as only one copy of the database exists.

Comment: A packaged solution for this can be found as `SQLiteAssetHelper`, rather than you rolling all your own code for it: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper